# Making generic function for setState()

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to write a generic function that can handle changes of multiple input fields, I did this in **React.js** before but I'm not that familiar with Dart, is there any way to make the "name" variable into an expression? any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

```
void updateChange(name, value) {
   setState(() {
      (Name of any variables) = value;
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Map` for your state, which is similar to a javascript object (or typescript `Record`, to be more precise).

```
Map<String, String> _state;


@override
void initState() {
  _state = {};
  // ...
  super.initState();
}

void updateChange(name, value) {
  setState(() {
    _state[name] = value;
  });
}
```